# Using binary type with NEST (elasticsearch)

Tags: elasticsearch, binary, nest, elasticsearch-net

I want to have a binary parameter stored in my Elasticsearch server from my C# code.
None of the types I tried to use in my index class translates to it.

Is there a way to explicitly instruct my program  to store a binary, say from a byte array (could be converted to other types of course)?

Alternatively, is there a way to configure the parameter not to be stored (like with the Json property `"stored": false`)? As the main problem for me is the copying and indexing of that big parameter (not ideal but sufficient)

Update: I tried to downgrade my NEST version to 1.6.1 to use the attribute

```
[ElasticProperty(Name = "Data", Type = FieldType.Binary, Store = false)]
public byte[] Data { get; set; }
```

But when I save a document with that property, it still insists to map a string (I check by running `GET mydb/_mapping` in my Sense plugin)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Elasticsearch supports binary types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/binary.html) which can be set using attributes within NEST using the following in NEST 1.x

```
public class Document
{
    [ElasticProperty(Type = FieldType.Binary, Store = false)]
    public string Binary { get; set; }
}
```

or

```
public class Document
{
    [Binary(Store= false)]
    public string Binary { get; set; }
}
```

in NEST 2.x

Note that the binary type should be sent to Elasticsearch as a base 64 encoded string ([1.x docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/mapping-core-types.html#binary) or [2.x docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/binary.html)). You could handle the conversion in your POCO type with something like (for 2.x)

```
public class Document
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public byte[] BinaryBytes { get; set;}

    [Binary]
    [JsonProperty("binary")]
    public string Binary
    {
        get
        {
            return BinaryBytes != null ? Convert.ToBase64String(BinaryBytes) : null;
        }
        protected set
        {
            if (value != null) BinaryBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(value);
        }
    }
}  

client.CreateIndex("index-name", c => c
    .Mappings(m => m
        .Map<Document>(d => d
            .AutoMap()
        )
    )
);
```

which yields

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "document": {
      "properties": {
        "binary": {
          "type": "binary"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you would set `BinaryBytes` on the model, and NEST would send the contents of `Binary` in the request. You could also make `Binary` a private property if it would be less confusing for users of the model.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your help, It seems that just adding the `client.CreateIndex` part instead of letting NEST doing it by itself gave me what I wanted

Comment: @OdedSayar there are two things that Elasticsearch does to help in getting up and running; first, create an index automatically if it does not yet exist. This behaviour can be controlled with - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#index-creation. Secondly, dynamically map (i.e. infer the types of) the fields of a document if an explicit mapping is not specified for the document type. This can also be controlled - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/dynamic-mapping.html